# em.contents is not a function on `mathjaxBind` directive

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, mathjax

I have directive using `mathjaxBind` but the problems such as below:

[image]

How to avoid such error?

The codes on `mathjaxBind` directive:

```
.directive("mathjaxBind", function($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            controller: ["$scope", "$element", "$attrs",
                function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                    $scope.$watch($attrs.mathjaxBind, function(texExpression) {
                        var em = $element.html(texExpression);
                        $compile(em.contents())($scope);
                        MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, $element[0]]);
                    });
                }]
        };
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

First parameter of `$scope.$watch` should be either `string` or `function`. If it is `string` it should be an [`expression`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression).

You pass `$attrs.mathjaxBind` (as a `string`) so it passes `undefined` in listener parameter `texExpression`. Method `html()` of `$element` instance doesn't return back this instance if you pass `undefined` into it (it returns empty string). Therefore you got an error.

You can set watcher as a function that returns value like in this [plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/3srp2PvFdMKpqgiSqblh?p=preview).